# How can I get specific section of string in .attr('href')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have data I am trying to scrape and format to JSON.

I am trying to get a specific section of a string in href

```html
<a href="javascript:PlaySample('Samples/01.mp3')">
  <img src="picts/samples-play.gif" border="0" class="Playborder" alt="play"></a>
```

I can get the string with

```js
const sample = $(this).find('img[class="Playborder"]').closest('a').attr('href');
```

```
"javascript:PlaySample('Samples/01.mp3')"
```

I only want whats inside the ('') so my thought was to use -

```js
const sample = $(this).find('img[class="Playborder"]').closest('a').attr('href').match(/\(\'.*\'\)/g);
```

```js
//object
{
 'sample': sample === null ? null  : sample[0]
}
```

But Im getting the error -

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Your `match` returns me `('Samples/01.mp3')` - exactly as regex says. Only one thing which I don't know in your code is what is in `$(this)` - it's probably any loop. When I take your HTML, your JS and use `$('img.Playborder').closest()...match(...)` I get what you want. https://jsfiddle.net/hjd8be70/

Comment: What is the context of `this`? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: It is in a loop so I was sometimes getting 'undefined', checking the type helped out thanks!